What is the ratio of the length $\text{PR}$ to the length $\text{QS}$?

In the rhombus below, the measure of angle $\angle \text{QRS}$ is $60^\circ$. What is the ratio of the length $\text{PR}$
to the length $\text{QS}$?


The author's answer is $$\frac{\text{PR}}{\text{QS}} = \sqrt{3}.$$
Could someone explain why this is the correct answer?

This doesn’t affect the answers below, but your diagram is a parallelogram, not a rhombus. And though both answers have diagrams, both are parallelograms, only one is a rhombus.


This is a rhombus: $PQ = QR = RS = SP = x$, and $PR$ and $QS$ are perpendicular bisectors of each other.
Given $\angle QRS = 60°$ and $QR = RS$ we know that these form an isosceles triangle, so $\angle RSQ = \angle SQR = \frac{180° - 60°}{2} = 60°$, so this is an equilateral triangle, so $QS = x$ as well.
Now, let's just consider a small triangle: we'll put $O$ at the intersection of $PR$ and $QS$, and look at $\triangle OPQ$, which is a right triangle from $O$.
$OQ = \frac{x}{2}$ and $PQ = x$, and by Pythagoras $OP^2 + OQ^2 = PQ^2$, so $OP^2 = x^2 - \frac{x^2}{4} = \frac{3x^2}{4}$, so $OP = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x$.  Thus $PR = 2OP = \sqrt{3}x$, so $\frac{PR}{QS} = \sqrt{3}$.


Let $AB \perp QR \iff AB \perp SP$.
let $AO=BO=h$ (the height is the same, because $\triangle QOR \cong \triangle SOP )$ and $\angle ARO = 30^{\circ} $ and $\angle OSB = 60^{\circ}$(sum of degrees of neighbour vertices sum to $180$ in a parallelogram)
Using some trigonometry we can see that $\sin(\angle ARO)= \sin(30^{\circ} ) =\frac{AO}{RO} =\frac{1}{2} $ and $\sin(\angle OSB) = \frac{BO}{SO} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $ and so if $AO=BO $ then $$ \frac{AO}{RO}=\frac{1}{2} $$
$$ \frac{AO}{SO}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\Rightarrow AO=\frac{SO\sqrt{3}}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{SO\sqrt{3}}{2RO}=\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow\frac{SO}{RO}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $$
Because $PR = 2 RO$ and $QS = 2 SO $ then we can conclude that $$ \frac{QS}{PR}=\frac{2SO}{2RO}=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
